# Heroku SSL Says Trusted, but redirects to http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, https

Problem: When entering `www.domainname.com` in the browser, I am redirected to `http://my domainname.com` and it says that the site is not trusted. I have followed the Heroku docs, but it still fails.

I am running Rails 3+ on Heroku Cedar Stack and added the SSL-Endpoint addon, uploaded the certs and private key, and forwarded the CName in the DNS to the NAME.herokussl.com url that was given to me via SSL-Endpoint. After running `heroku certs`, it says `Trusted: true`. I have waited 24+ hrs after setting the CNames in Namecheap, but still cannot use the https secure address. Does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line to my `production.rb` file fixed the issue for me.

```
#app/config/environments/production.rb
config.force_ssl = true
```

Comment: I tried that, but then got an infinite redirect. I found out the problem. I am using Spree, and Spree only uses SSL for data sensitive pages: Signin/Signout, and Checkout. It works fine for those pages, but I did not realize it. Does anyone think that not having SSL on the store products pages is a problem?